# Вывод данных из таблицы в разные блоки div class

Tags: php

Нужно вывести значения из таблицы в один div блок, где две заметки (картинка, название, краткое описание и т.д.). И есть второй div блок, где шесть заметок (картинка и название). Только не объясняйте пожалуйста для числовых значений, а для строчных, не как немогу разобраться.

```html
                    <?php if($brands): ?>
                    <div class="block-content">
                        <div class="container cf">
                            <div class="large b-row cf">
                                <!--Здесь выводится 2 первые заметки, с этим проблем нет, limit=2-->
                                <?php foreach($brands as $brand): ?>
                                <div class="column half b-col">
                                    <article>
                                        <a href="#"> </a>
                                        <h2 class="post-title"><a href="#"><?=$brand->title;?></a></h2>
                                        <div class="cf listing-meta meta below"> <span class="meta-item author"><?=$brand->title;?> <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-comments-o"></i> 3</a></span></div>
                                        <div class="excerpt">
                                            <p><?=$brand->description;?></p>
                                        </div>
                                    </article>
                                </div>
                                <?php endforeach; ?>
                            </div>
                            <!--А как быть дальше и вывести еще 6 заметок из тойже таблицы ума неприлажу-->
                            <ul class="b-row posts-list thumb">
                                <?php $last_brands = array_slice($brands, 2); ?>
                                <li class="column half b-col">
                                    <article class="post cf">
                                        <a href="#"> </a>
                                        <div class="content">
                                            <a href="#"><?=$brand->title;?></a>
                                            <div class="cf listing-meta below"> <time datetime="2017-01-10T03:34:37+00:00" class="meta-item">Jan 10, 2017</time></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </article>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: вам ответ тоже картинкой отправить?

Comment: Укажите в вопросе содержимое массива `$brands` и уточните, какие значения вам нужно вывести в списке `<ul>`.

Comment: в чем проблема то? я так понял, у вас 8 записей. две первых надо с одной версткой вывести и еще 6 с другой.  разделите массив на два, в первом - 2 записи, во втором 6. Далее сделать два цикла вывода для каждого.

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете обрезать первые 2 элемента массива и вывести следующие с помощью функции array_slice

```
 $last_brands = array_slice($brands, 2);
```

Comment: тогда уж сделать сразу два массива $rest = array_splice($brands, -6);

Comment: Покажите пожалуйста на коде, как мне это осуществить.